# Is there any command to minimize windows?

Tags: command-line, window, minimize

I work all-around in **Ubuntu 14.04** with many programs opened, among them **the terminal**. It would be very useful to me **a command to minimize and maximize windows**.
I have searched in the web using various languages for my search, but I've found anything about a command like that.
 It seems to me impossible that so basic commands do not exist yet.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it.

Open your terminal and paste following command

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then

execute below command in terminal

```
xdotool key <your_keyboard_hotkey>
```

To minimize all windows hotkey is Control-Super-D so

```
  xdotool key CTRL+Super+D
```

To minimize a window

```
 xdotool key Alt+Space+n
```

To maximize

```
  xdotool key Alt+Space+x
```

will minimize and one more thing is you can use alias and can give a name to call this command.

Hope it will works

Comment: This only covers showing the desktop, and does not cover the specifics of the question.

Comment: @RolandiXor my intention was to give some idea on achieving, I have give complete answer now.

Comment: in future, just give the complete answer at once in a case like this. The original answer came across as though it wasn't really answering the question.

Comment: Thanks @Raja for the answer. It worked. I have proven **xdotools** and **wmctrl**, as it was suggested in the previous question about this subject (I hadn't seen that one, sorry for this duplicate). Nevertheless **those commands only work if you want to manage a single window** from the terminal each time; they seem to not work if you want to send an order to many windows. For example, I have opened two windows of Cherrytree (its filenames end with .ctx or .ctb), and I send `xdotool search --name ctx windowminimize` and only one of two windows get the order. That's similar for _wmctrl_